# Multiple jquery dialogs in index.php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

The general idea is to make a site that looks like windows enviroment, so I have add two icons for example and when someone click on them, takes two different dialog boxes.

In to my site's index page I have add this inside head tags:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"
/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<!-- JQUERY DIALOG SCRIPT -->
<script>
    var $JQ_ = jQuery.noConflict();
    $JQ_(function () {
        $JQ_("#rl_module_dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 'auto',
            resizable: false,
            show: {
                effect: "fade",
                duration: 250
            },
            hide: {
                effect: "fade",
                duration: 250
            }
        });
        $JQ_("#opener").click(function () {
            $JQ_("#rl_module_dialog").dialog("open");
        });
    });
</script>
```

I also have two separated php files that are icluded into my index page and they contain this...

**First:**

```
<div id="rl_module_dialog" class="rl_module_dialog" title=""><?php include '**/**/something.php'; ?></div>
<div class="nm_icon" id="opener"><div class="icon">&nbsp;</div></div>
```

**Second**

```
<div id="rl_module_dialog" class="rl_module_dialog" title=""><?php include '**/**/something_else.php'; ?></div>
<div class="vath_icon" id="opener"><div class="icon">&nbsp;</div></div>
```

If I don't include the second one, dialog works fine. If I place them both, none is working! There is any way to use my jquery dialog script for more than one dialog in same page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that **IDs must be unique on the page.**

So, you should simply give different IDs to your dialogs. Something like `#rl_module_dialog_1` and 
`#rl_module_dialog_2`

Later you can initialize those dialogs like:

```
$JQ_("#rl_module_dialog_1,#rl_module_dialog_2").dialog({...});
```

And of course, to open dialogs, you will need to specify corresponding id:

```
$JQ_("#rl_module_dialog_1").dialog("open");
```

**Edit:**

In order to not place a lot of click handlers for each icon, you can do something like this:

```
<div class="rl_module_dialog" id="dialog1" title="">Dialog 1</div>
<div class="nm_icon opener" data-dialog="dialog1"><div class="icon">Open 1</div></div>
<div class="rl_module_dialog" id="dialog2" title="">Dialog 2</div>
<div class="nm_icon opener" data-dialog="dialog2"><div class="icon">Open 2</div></div>
```

See icon divs now have `data-dialog=""` - that is to specify ID of dialog which should be opened when icon is clicked.

And single click handler for all dialogs:

```
$(".opener").click(function () {            
     $("#" + $(this).data("dialog")).dialog("open");
});
```

`$(this).data("dialog")` takes `data-dialog` value.
Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/X6qhH/3/

Comment: It works but I need something more "compact"... My code will look like holy book if I have to add one by one all those dialogs!!! There isn't any way using `while` or something? PS: I am totally new in jQuery. Thank you for your time!!!

Comment: add one by one in which case? when you want to open? Or create dialog? You can always use common class instead of IDs. Something like `$JQ_(".rl_module_dialog").dialog({...});` this will initialize all dialogs with class `rl_module_dialog`

Comment: I am talking about this part... `$JQ_("#rl_module_dialog_1").dialog("open");`.

Comment: Well, not sure why do you need to open ALL dialogs with one click, but you should be able to do that by using class: `$JQ_(".rl_module_dialog").dialog("open");`

Comment: I think I typed it wrong... I want every dialog open separately but into the code if I can make it more compact.

Comment: Hm. You must specify dialog ID (or any other selector identifying it) and apply `.dialog("open")`. You can wrap that code in some custom function `function dlgo(s) {$JQ_(s).dialog("open");}` and will have something like `dlgo("#rl_module_dialog_1")`. instead of full code.

Comment: I don't want to type `dlgo("#rl_module_dialog_1")` and `dlgo("#rl_module_dialog_2")` and `dlgo("#rl_module_dialog_3")` etc. Just one for everyone!!! This is what I mean.

Comment: Ok. You will have a lot of icons, each icon will open own dialog. But you do not want to create a lot of .click handlers, right?

Answer (score 0):

Both those dialogs have the same id. make the second dialog have `id="rl_module_dialog2"` and initialize it

```
$JQ_("#rl_module_dialog2").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    width: 'auto',
    resizable: false,
    show: {
        effect: "fade",
        duration: 250
    },
    hide: {
        effect: "fade",
        duration: 250
    }
});
```

and just have your opener button open both like

```
$JQ_("#opener").click(function(){
    $JQ_("#rl_module_dialog").dialog("open");
    $JQ_("#rl_module_dialog2").dialog("open");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all. Do not use multiple IDs on the same page.

That said, I've redone your code to work with multiple instances of jQuery UI's dialog.

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/rgin/PaYLb/)

```
var $JQ_ = jQuery.noConflict();

$JQ_('.rl_module_dialog').hide();

$JQ_('.opener').each( function() {
    $JQ_.data(this, 'dialog',
           $JQ_(this).prev('.rl_module_dialog').dialog({
               autoOpen: false,
               width: 'auto',
               resizable: false,
               show: {
                   effect: 'fade',
                   duration: 250
               },
               hide: {
                   effect: 'fade',
                   duration: 250
               }
           })
     );
}).click( function() {
    $JQ_.data(this, 'dialog').dialog('open');
});
```

Hopefully, this works for you.

Comment: I did as you said my friend and it works only the first icon. Plus when I click on it opens both dialogs at once!!! You are too close, any correction? Thank you for your time...

Comment: Check my edit. This solution is based solely on the html that you've give on your question.

Comment: I now it is working on **jsfiddle** but it isn't working on my case... I checked the code "character by character" and there is no errors!!! If it works I'll inform you...

Comment: Try posting your code as a fiddle. It might be your html that is causing the issue.

Comment: Again, try posting your code on jsfiddle, or show me your site. I'd be glad to help, but can't without seeing your code. :)

Comment: You have to give me an email or something and send you login info... What I am making now is only viewable by admin!!!

Comment: I don't think that's necessary. Also, I wouldn't give strangers admin access to sites I build if I were you. No matter, how helpful they seem. That said, if you can't post a fiddle or come up with a way to show the site without giving me admin access, I'm afraid this is all that I can do. =/

Comment: I wouldn't give you admin access my friend... Any way, thank you for your advice and your valuable time!!! Your example were correct even if it didn't work for me. :)

Comment: Try checking your HTML, see if the classes are the same and all.

Answer (score 0):

use different id for div then it may fixed

first :

```
<div id="rl_module_dialog" class="rl_module_dialog" title=""><?php include '**/**/something.php'; ?></div>
<div class="nm_icon" id="opener"><div class="icon">&nbsp;</div></div>
```

second:

```
<div id="rl_module_dialog_two" class="rl_module_dialog" title=""><?php include '**/**/something_else.php'; ?></div>
<div class="vath_icon" id="opener"><div class="icon">&nbsp;</div></div>



<script>
    var $JQ_ = jQuery.noConflict();
    $JQ_(function () {
        $JQ_("#rl_module_dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 'auto',
            resizable: false,
            show: {
                effect: "fade",
                duration: 250
            },
            hide: {
                effect: "fade",
                duration: 250
            }
        });
        $JQ_("#opener").click(function () {
            $JQ_("#rl_module_dialog_two").dialog("open");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

dialog id's should like this

`rl_module_dialog_1`

`rl_module_dialog_2`

shortest code

```
$JQ_('[id^="rl_module_dialog"]').dialog({...});
```

to open you can use

```
$JQ_("#rl_module_dialog_1").dialog("open");
```

[attribute-equals-selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

`^` [attribute-starts-with-selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

```
Description: Selects elements that have the specified attribute with 
a value beginning exactly with a given string.
```

Comment: It is working... But there is no way to do something similar `$JQ_('[id^="rl_module_dialog"]')` at open part and don't have to write one by one those dialogs?